# Unable to connect Plesk MySQL from remote server

Tags: plesk, database-connection

I am trying to connect to Plesk MySQL server from another server. I am trying to access it using IP address But It always gives the error like.

> "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' (4)"

Remote access setting of MySQL server are ."Allow remote connections from any host"

Comment: What OS have you using? Try to check firewall settings on plesk server.

Comment: Changed the wording is title to make it more like a question rather than statement

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps to "Allow remote connections from any host" :

1. Open a DOS command prompt on the server.
2. Run the following command from the mysql\bin directory:

   {mysql -u root --password=}
3. A mysql prompt should be displayed.
4. To create a remote user account with root privileges, run the following commands:

   {GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'IP'  IDENTIFIED  BY 'PASSWORD';}

'USERNAME' is the username to be created.
'IP' is the public IP address of the remote connection.
'PASSWORD' is the password to be assigned for this username.
(IP can be replaced with % to allow this user to logon from any host or IP)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/my.cnf` and change to (via ssh):

```sh
bind-address = ::
```

And restart db:

```sh
service mariadb restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short. You can't. Your provider does not have that featured enabled. Switch to cPanel providers.